# Open duplicate viewControllers on cell selection in tableView (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, duplicates

I'm making a `TableView` and I want each cell to open a copy of a `ViewController` I've created.

Is it possible? I've searched for that but I really cannot find anything helpful.

Comment: Consider adding an example(e.g.: An image of your storyboard/some things you have tried so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var viewController: UIViewController?

    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            viewController = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)
        case 1:
            viewController = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)
        case 2:
            viewController = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)
    }

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thank you ! but if i don't know the number of "new viewController" there is a way to not write each vieController with identifier?
like Apple's note app?

Comment: How do you know otherwise which `viewController` each cell should present?

Comment: like the native note application: 
each time we create a new note, it's a new viewcontroller duplicated but empty.

Comment: Then you don't need the switch: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let  viewController = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}`

Comment: Did you set `UITableViewDelegate`? Do you have `UINavigationController`?

Comment: il est mis en storyboard et non, je ne pas utiliser NavigationController. so I essayé d'intégrer le "nouveau viewcontroller" dans un NavigationController mais toujours rien